# Is it an anti-pattern to use inheritance when handling RecyclerView list items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two classes I want to mix and match into a recyclerView, ItemA and ItemB. In order to do this I've given them a base class of BaseItem so they can be passed in as one List. Then in my RecyclerAdapter's getItemViewType method I work out what the class is so I can use the correct Viewholder.

At this point my internal anti-pattern instincts started flaring up. I generally feel that if you have to work out what the concrete class is to handle an object then it shouldn't have a base class. Is this the wrong way to go about doing this? I've been unable to find any examples of people doing similarly.

Is there a good alternative to this?
I put together some code to illustrate my point.

```
public class ItemRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private static final int TYPE_A = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_B = 1;

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<BaseItem> items;

    public ItemRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<BaseItem> items, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        switch (viewType) {

            case TYPE_A:

                ViewGroup v = //   Get viewGroup
                ViewHolderA viewHolderA = new ViewHolderA(v);
                return viewHolderA;

            default:

                ViewGroup defaultViewGroup = // Get viewGroup
                ViewHolderB viewHolderB = new ViewHolderB(defaultViewGroup);
                return viewHolderB;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        BaseMenuItem item = items.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {


            case TYPE_A:

                ViewHolderA va = (ViewHolderA) holder;
                ViewHolderA.setData((ItemA) item);

                break;

            case TYPE_B:

                ViewHolderB vb = (ViewHolderB) holder;
                ViewHolderB.setData((ItemB) item);

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        BaseMenuItem item = items.get(position);

        boolean IsItemTypeA = item.getClass() == ItemA.class;
        if (IsItemTypeA) {
            return TYPE_A;
        }

        return TYPE_B;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (items == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return items.size();
    }

    public abstract class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolderA extends BaseViewHolder {
        //  ViewHolder stuff here.
    }

    private class ViewHolderB extends BaseViewHolder {
        //  ViewHolder stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out liskov substitution principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not consider it an anti pattern. For those scenarios Ive implemented a pattern called delegate adapter which is a modification from an idea of [this](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates) article (lecture recommended).

I do recommend though some modifications to your current implementation:

- Specify an abstract method in `BaseItem` that declares its view type, and let it children implement said method. Something like `getViewType` that way you avoid the nasty `getClass` comparison.
- Store your registered view types in a utility class or even better a IntDef definition for clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

M personal opinion, is that it would be considered an anti-pattern if those two models have no *logical* relationship, hence not sharing any common attributes, or cannot be expressed with an abstraction.

If your only goal is to only pass in a list containing both models, pass a `List<Object>`